# How is food-grade calcium sulfate made?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, extraction

I'm doing a chemistry project on ionic compounds found on food labels, and I can't find a clear article on how calcium sulfate is made for edible foods. I know it comes from calcium sulfate dihydrate. I have found articles on how they turn that into calcium sulfate for fertilizer, concrete, drywall, and other materials, but not for food products.

Answer (score 3):

Use of calcium sulfate in food and pharmaceutical applications is widespread
and continues to expand. United States Gypsum Company offers two highly refined calcium sulfate products: USG Terra Alba and SNOW WHITE filler. Both fillers are food- and pharmaceutical-grade forms of calcium sulfate, a mineral that appears on the Food and Drug Administration’s GRAS (Generally Recognized as Safe) list of additives approved for nutritional and functional use in food products.

- USG Terra Alba ($\ce{CaSO4 \cdot 2H2O}$), the dihydrate form of calcium sulfate, results from fine-grinding and air-separating a select, high-purity white gypsum that contains about $20$ percent water of crystallization.
- SNOW WHITE filler ($\ce{CaSO4}$), the anhydrous form of calcium
  sulfate, is produced by calcining and milling high-purity white
  gypsum$^{[1]}$.

Gypsum is made suitable for commercial use by a process called calcination, which involves heating the mineral to remove approximately three-quarters of its water. Calcined gypsum can recrystallize into any shape with the simple addition of water.$^{[2]}$.

Presumably through repeated calcination, gypsum is made pure enough to meet FDA standards.

---

<sub>$^{[1]}$ [USG, Calcium Sulfate Fillers](https://www.usg.com/content/dam/USG_Marketing_Communications/united_states/product_promotional_materials/finished_assets/calcium-sulfate-filler-brochure-en-IG172.pdf)

$^{[2]}$ [Encyclopedia.com, USG Corporation](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/USG_Corp.aspx)</sub>